# How to make a Bresenham's line algorithm?

Tags: java, line

I wrote a small program, that draws a line from user inputs x1,y1 and x2,y2. For some reason line only works while horizontal, but once line should be vertical, it just shows me a black pixel not a line. I have checked everything and I am pretty sure that I got the algorithm right, but problem is still here.

```
int x1 = Integer.parseInt(this.jTextFieldX1.getText());
    int y1 = Integer.parseInt(this.jTextFieldY1.getText());
    int x2 = Integer.parseInt(this.jTextFieldX2.getText());
    int y2 = Integer.parseInt(this.jTextFieldY2.getText());

    int xi = x2 > x1 ? 1:-1;
    int yi = y2 > y1 ? 1:-1;

    int dx = Math.abs(x2-x1);
    int dy = Math.abs(y2-y1);

    int xn= x1;
    int yn= y1;
    int pn;
    canvas.showBlackPixel(xn,yn);

    if (dx > dy)
    {
        pn= 2*dy - dx;
        while (xn != x2)
        {    
        if (pn >0)
        {
            xn=xn + xi;
            yn=yn + yi;
            pn=pn + 2*dy - 2*dx;

        }
        else
        {  
               xn = xn + xi;
               pn = pn+ 2*dy;
        }
        canvas.showBlackPixel(xn,yn);
        }
        { 

        if (dy > dx)
    {
        pn= 2*dx - dy;
        while (yn != y2)
        {    
        if (pn > 0)
        {
            xn=xn + xi;
            yn=yn + yi;
            pn=pn + 2*dx - 2*dy;


        }
        else
        {  
               yn = yn + yi;
               pn = pn + 2*dx;
        }
        canvas.showBlackPixel(xn,yn);
        }

        }

        }






    }


}
```

How could I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the termination of your statements, which is to say your braces {} are mixed up a little.  To be specific, cut down to the relevant bits your code is:

```
    if (dx > dy) 
    {
        ...
        if (dy > dx) 
        {
            ...
        }
    }
```

If you fix your braces, then it looks like it should work better.

```
    if (dx > dy) 
    {
        ...
    }
    if (dy > dx) 
    {
        ...
    }
```

You'll still have an issue when dx == dy though.